# Cannot call and override function when extending base class uses Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, extending

I extending base class (Class A) that uses redux and I want to call and override function in base class but it not working. Give me solutions thank you.

Parent Class: https://ibb.co/bNzPRZ6

Child Class: https://ibb.co/vX1xPvq

Result: https://ibb.co/GFYRtQY

**Parent Class:**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class ClassA extends Component {

    showAlertMess(message) {
        alert(message)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View></View>
        );
    }
}
export default connect()(ClassA)
```

**Child Class:**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import ClassA from './classA';

export default class ClassB extends ClassA {
    state = {  }

    componentDidMount(){
    this.showAlertMess("This is class B")
}

    render() {
        return (
            <View></View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code directly to the question

Comment: I added code in my question, thank you.